# How to correctly implement a button that changes to an input element, WCAG Accessibility friendly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I believe this is a classic problem with a button that changes into an input field when the button is clicked. What more should be done other than setting the focus on the input field?
Should the screen reader get notified, or is there anything else I should think about regarding aria-tags, maybe `aria-haspopup`? Please help me figure out how to do this right

`isOpen ? <input /> : <button />`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, WCAG standards suggest multiple ways which you can implement in order to check the boxes for users who rely on screen readers and assistive technologies as per your requirement. Some of them which are pretty much the standards like:

- Allowing Navigations over input fields using keyboard. You might want to check ***[`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)***
- Using `aria-live: polite` attribute to le the user know around the change. For instance, you can include the message "XYZ input field active" when the input field is displayed. There is an ***[`reac-aria-live`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aria-live)*** module which you might want to take a look.
- You can also use the ***[`ARIA` roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role)*** and attributes on button clicks and on various input field events. Some of them are like: `aria-expanded`, `button roles`, etc.